# how to include ngFileSaver in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying this

```
var app = angular.module('familyInfo');

app.controller('familyInfoController',
  ['$scope','$http','$rootScope', '$location', 'ngFileSaver',
  function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location, FileSaver) {
      //some functions
}]);
```

but I am getting this Error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngFileSaverProvider - ngFileSaver
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/$injector/unpr?p0=ngFileSaverProvider%20%3C-%20ngFileSaver

What should I do any suggestions?

Comment: your module doesn't have a reference to `ngFileSaver`. Did you inject it  in the main module (`angular.module('familyInfo', ['ngFileSaver'])`)? What is the order of your scripts?

Comment: Have you included the `angular-file-saver.bundle.js` in your html before your controller file?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

```
function ExampleCtrl(FileSaver, Blob) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.val = {
    text: 'Hey ho lets go!'
  };

  vm.download = function(text) {
    var data = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(data, 'text.txt');
  };
}

angular
  .module('fileSaverExample', ['ngFileSaver'])
  .controller('ExampleCtrl', ['FileSaver', 'Blob', ExampleCtrl]);
```

you need to have a dependency in your module as well.